# Are there still plans for a new sound theme?

Tags: sound, themes

Let me quote from [Mark's blog](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/308#comment-324337) almost one year ago:

> *March 5th, 2010 at 7:19 pm*
>   Mark, will there be an update to the sound theme to match the updated visual brand?
>
> *Mark Shuttleworth:* Gack, I completely forgot about that. A very good point. Would you see if you can rally a round of community submissions for a sound theme inspired by light?

Let's keep it short and sweet: **What are the current considerations for the Ubuntu default sound theme?**

---

**Update, October 5 2011**

This question was "answered" before the release of Natty. However, it proved to be wrong in the mean time. So the legacy continues, and I am reopening this one.

---

**Update, February 15, 2012**

Something is rolling! Looks like there will be a new sound for 12.04. Only a start-up sound however, no complete theme.

http://design.canonical.com/2012/02/sound-theme-update/

---

**Update, April 30, 2012**

It seemed to look good, but for some reason the sound did not make it into 12.04. There have been no announcements as to why, however. The sound theme remains a mistery...

---

**Update, May 2, 2012**

Mark Shuttleworth made a statement on IRC recently saying that it simply "was not perfect yet." It will maybe be in 12.10 then.

---

**Update, December 6, 2012**

Not in 12.10, either. But - there's still hope for 13.04!

---

*As of the last update, the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-sounds/+bug/539169) for getting a new sound theme has been marked as Confirmed (but not In Progress) with the last comment posted October 31, 2011.*

---

**Update, September 11, 2013**

Won't be in 13.04, and neither in 13.10. However, an interesting proposal has popped up. The composer of the "Mass Effect" soundtrack offered to make  a startup sound for Ubuntu [on this mailing list](https://lists.launchpad.net/unity-design/msg10267.html).

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/mass-effect-composer-ubuntu-14-04-start-up-sounds

Discussion on Reddit [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1m659a/mass_effect_composer_offers_to_create_new_ubuntu/).

Answer (score 13):

There will be a new startup sound for 12.04, chosen from one of the 4 finalists. Listen to them [here](http://design.canonical.com/2012/02/sound-theme-update/) and fill out this [survey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/3DLBM9X) to help decide the new startup sound for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Well, that explains :). Cheers!

Comment: Let's revisit this question! Now we have 11.10 and there still is no new theme.

Comment: Can you update your answer? We have some activity!
http://design.canonical.com/2012/02/sound-theme-update/

Comment: Very interesting: the sound did not make it into Precise. Any ideas why?

Comment: This is something that individual users should configure on their own, It would just be one more thing to turn off if was implemented. Its something that I always turn off on Mac and Win.

Answer (score -3):

While I was testing Ubuntu 11.04 when you log into the desktop there is no start up sound that usually goes off. So maybe they have removed the old sound to get ready for the new one. I hope so.

Comment: It is still alpha so that might still change.

Comment: I get the startup sound on my 11.04 laptop. The sound theme's still there.